# Node.js UDP Multicast over Network

Tags: javascript, node.js, network-programming, udp, multicast

I'm having an issue with a repeated `EADDRNOTAVAIL` issue on a UDP multicast proof of concept. I have a Linux server sending multicast messages to a Windows client (have tried reversing this to no avail..). The server works correctly when running **both** the client and the server on the same machine, but not over the *same* network.

Below is the code I've tried to get this to work with, the IPs I'm using, and the errors I've received.

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly!

---

### Environment

Windows Local IP: `192.168.1.10`
Linux Local IP: `192.168.1.11`

### Server: `server.js`

```
const SRC_PORT = 6025;
const PORT = 6024;
const MULTICAST_ADDR = '239.255.255.250';
const LOCAL_IP = '192.168.1.11';
const dgram = require('dgram');
const server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

server.bind(SRC_PORT, LOCAL_IP, function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    let message = new Buffer(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    server.send(message, 0, message.length, PORT, MULTICAST_ADDR, function () {
      console.log("Sent '" + message + "'");
    });
  }, 4000);
});
```

### Client: `client.js`

```
const PORT = 6024;
const MULTICAST_ADDR = '239.255.255.250';
const LOCAL_IP = '192.168.1.10';
const HOST_IP = '192.168.1.11';
const dgram = require('dgram');
const client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

client.on('listening', function () {
  let address = client.address();
  console.log('UDP Client listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

client.on('message', function (message, rinfo) {
  console.log('Message from: ' + rinfo.address + ':' + rinfo.port + ' - ' + message);
});

//*** Also tried with client.bind(PORT, LOCAL_IP, ... and failed
client.bind(PORT, function () {
  client.addMembership(MULTICAST_ADDR, HOST_IP);
});
```

### Error

```
dgram.js:508
    throw errnoException(err, 'addMembership');
    ^

Error: addMembership EADDRNOTAVAIL
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at Socket.addMembership (dgram.js:508:11)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (~/dev/node-multicast/client.js:16:10)
    at Socket.g (events.js:286:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at startListening (dgram.js:121:10)
    at dgram.js:228:7
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you joined wrong multicastInterface from this error:

> addMembership EADDRNOTAVAIL

It should be your address of local interface:
`client.addMembership(MULTICAST_ADDR, LOCAL_IP);`

As the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_socket_addmembership_multicastaddress_multicastinterface) says:

> `socket.addMembership(multicastAddress[, multicastInterface])`
>   Tells the kernel to join a multicast group at the given
>   multicastAddress and multicastInterface using the IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP
>   socket option. If the multicastInterface argument is not specified,
>   the operating system will choose one interface and will add membership
>   to it. To add membership to every available interface, call
>   addMembership multiple times, once per interface.

Comment: Wow. I knew I was missing something simple. Thank you so much! Changing the address on the client to *its own local IP address* (`192.168.1.10` in the code) worked!